# php join query for multiple tables

Tags: php, join

Can anyone tell me how i can get the value for project_title, project_id, level_of_want, and selection_id. When i submit this i get No database selected error.

```
$query_Name = "SELECT u.Student_Surname, u.Student_Forename, p2.Project_Title,     
p2.Project_id, s.level_of_want, s.selection_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN projects p2 ON u.id = p2.Project_Lecturer
INNER JOIN selection s ON p2.Project_id = s.id_project
INNER JOIN users u2 ON s.student_id = u2.id
WHERE u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']." ORDER BY selection_id ASC" ;
$Name = mysql_query($query_Name, $projectsite) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Name = mysql_fetch_assoc($Name);
$totalRows_Name = mysql_num_rows($Name);
```

Comment: did you open a db connection with mysql_select_db and mysql_connect previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after connecting to mysql server base you should explicitly select database using [mysql_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) function

Comment: Sorry i rushed to enter. I meant i cant get the values as when i submit i get the No database selected error.

Comment: @NathanLinkAbiola `mysql_select_db('db_name')` must be missing in connection.

Comment: Thanks lads, seemed i had the mysql_select_db in the wrong location

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_select_db($bd);
```

we need to see how do you connect

Comment: mysql_select_db($database_projectsite, $projectsite);

Comment: and how do you set the $projectsite